# Python Relative Import Shared C++ Library

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

Say I have a folder structure like this:

```
run.py
lib
|-- __init__.py
|-- pkg1
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- mod1.so
|-- pkg2
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- mod2.py
```

Where `mod1.so` is a C++ shared library. In `mod2.py` I have a relative import statement `from ..pgk1 import mod1`, and in `run.py` I have `import lib.pkg2.mod2` If I run `python run.py` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: ./lib/pkg1/mod1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas why the improt won't work?

Comment: In mod.py -> you mean in mod2.py ?

Comment: Yes, It was a typo.